# How to use type-safe query and avoid querying nested entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.2

I'm using JPA 2.2 with Hibernate 5.2 implementation.

I have the following entity:

```
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private String customer;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn((name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID_ORDER")
    private Shipping shipping;

    ... get and set
}
```

Now I want to query ONLY Order fields (no nestend entity properties) in one select.

This is my code:

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Order> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery( Order.class );
final Root<Order> orderRoot = criteria.from( Order.class );
criteria.where( criteriaBuilder.equal( orderRoot.get( Order_.customer ), customer ) );
criteria.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(orderRoot.get(Order_.dt)));
final List<Order> output = entityManager.createQuery( criteria ).getResultList();
return output;
```

By setting hibernate show_sql=true, on my Unit Test I discovered that for each result there is a select for **shipping** entity property.
Something like:

```
 select order0_.id, order0_.customer from Order ..
 select ordershipping0_.id, ordershipping0_.email from Shipping ...
 select ordershipping0_.id, ordershipping0_.email from Shipping ...
 select ordershipping0_.id, ordershipping0_.email from Shipping ...
 select ordershipping0_.id, ordershipping0_.email from Shipping ...
```

How can I avoid that ?

It would be even better to choose specific columns for Order, altough I want to return always the *Order* class

**PS**
I wish to use JPA native code, no Hibernate specific implementation if possible

**EDIT**
I noticed that entities are automatically fetched if nestedProperty has a referencedColumn to parent.pk column.. this sounds odd anyway

Comment: Is shipping field nullable?

Comment: You have to set optional = false -> @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: Yes, it is nullable. I set optional = false but it doesn't change :(

Comment: As far as I know using FetchType.LAZY your field can not be nullable

Comment: If you refer to columns "ID" and "ID_ORDER" then they are NOT NULLABLE.
Shipping property however may be not present

Comment: I have a doubt: as id column is also the PK of order, is it possible that it automatically fetches all nested entities which have a reference to its pk ?

Comment: Do you have "id" column mapped twice in the entity?